# issues logging in to a terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2008

When i log on to terminal server i get a pop-up box from windows 7 asking me my credentials...
Usually after entering them it would go straight through to the desktop of the terminal server.
However now once I enter them it take me to the logon screen on Terminal Server with my account pictures and asked for a password and username once more then lets me in?

any ideas - very annoying

Comment: Do you control the terminal server or just a user of the server?

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox setting inside GPO's and "Terminal Server Configuration" on servers that "always prompt for password" (Log on Settings tab) that could be the cause.

Also, if your Remote Desktop Connection client (under settings) has Remote Desktop Gateway enabled (aka TSG) and it's using one, it will require logging onto that gateway before logging on the server.